# Read from file and not closing it?

Tags: java, android

I have some data stored in file. I have to read some data from file, do something with it and then write it to new file, and then again read - calculate - write, and so on.

My problem is, that I have method for reading bytes from file and every time this method is called I open file, read and then close. Same thing at writing.

I think because of this my app is very slow, because opening and closing files is taking some time for sure.

For reading I'm using RandomAccessFile class, and FileWritter for writting. Is there any way, that both of the files will be opened all the time from first reading and writing and just closed at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be opening and closing the file that causes slowness.  However reading and writing files can be slow, especially if writing to the sd card.  Just opening it should be pretty quick.

Also, for writing make sure you use a buffered writer in there somewhere.  It will greatly increase your speed if you aren't just writing the whole file as a big block.  If you're reading in the entire file you should use a buffered reader as well.